# Is there a way to reassign list variables within a CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I have the code below:

```
    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime

    today = str(day + " " + month_short + " " + year) #Variable providing dd/mm/yy
    read = pd.read_excel('local_file.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet 1', header=1, skipfooter=7)
    read.to_csv('file.csv', index=None, header=True)
    with open(txt, newline='') as csvfile:
        stats = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
        rows = list(stats)
        for x in range(len(rows)):
            var = today + str(rows[x])
            print(var)
```

It is currently returning me this:

```
    10 Sep 2021['Ascendas', 'REIT,A17U,20.345491,-4.149293']
    10 Sep 2021['CapitaLand,C31,18.699506,-4.605721']
    10 Sep 2021['CapitaLand', 'Integrated', 'Commercial', 'Trust,C38U,2.0973660000000005,11.301549999999999']        
    10 Sep 2021['City', 'Developments,C09,6.502435,-1.7483140000000001']
```

Snippet of the csv file:

Ascendas REIT,A17U,20.345491,-4.149293
CapitaLand,C31,18.699506,-4.605721
CapitaLand Integrated Commercial Trust,C38U,2.0973660000000005,11.301549999999999
City Developments,C09,6.502435,-1.7483140000000001

Is there a way to alter the lists such that it will display values in the format `['name', 'a', 'b', 'c']` e.g. `['Ascendas REIT','A17U','20.345491','-4.149293']`  for all of the lists?

Comment: did you try `splitt(',')`?

Comment: Tried using `split(',')`  on both `stats` and `rows`.  Both times returned the error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'.

Comment: Can you give a snippet of the csv file you are reading in?

Comment: @belfner Added a snippet to the post.

Comment: I think you need to change the specified delimiter in `csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')`. Change it to `','`.

Comment: Yup that did the trick for me. Thank you! To clarify, this worked because the csv file used ',' to separate the values, hence by having the delimiter set as ',', it allows the output to retain the same separation of values of the csv file. Is that correct?

Comment: @MinMin yes that's a correct explanation.